# Comparing coefficient across groups in 3 way linear mixed model

Tags: mixed-model, regression-coefficients, cohens-d, wald-test

I wonder how to compare coefficients across group in linear mixed model.

Dependent variable (DV, continuous variable) is changed by time variable (T, continuous, fixed effect).
And hypothesis is that 2 moderator variables (MV1 and MV2, categorical by 0 or 1, independent variable, fixed effects) affect the association of DV with T.
There is one covariate as continuous variable
Study participants (S) are considered as random effect.

```
m <-lmer(DV ~ MV1*MV2*T + (1|S) + CV, REML=T, data=data)
```

And result was

```
Fixed effects:
                                       Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                            18.55909    4.74223  300.00698   3.914 0.000113 ***
MV1                                   -5.92450    1.32025  318.51178  -4.487 1.01e-05 ***
MV2                                   -0.65531    1.39709  324.53991  -0.469 0.639349    
T                                      0.14929    0.01166 1518.32489  12.804  < 2e-16 ***
CV                                    -0.03221    0.06305  298.48239  -0.511 0.609864    
MV1:MV2                                3.24588    1.89431  321.91658   1.713 0.087584 .  
MV1:T                                 -0.09325    0.01333 1517.30915  -6.997 3.91e-12 ***
MV2:T                                  0.09113    0.01780 1517.49347   5.120 3.44e-07 ***
MV1:MV2:T                             -0.05137    0.02134 1518.24445  -2.407 0.016204 *
```

I found that interaction term (MV1 X MV2 X T) was significant.
When i divide whole population in 4 groups, like
MV1 = 0 and MV2 = 0
MV1 = 1 and MV2 = 0
MV1 = 0 and MV2 = 1
MV1 = 1 and MV2 = 1

How can i statistically compare coefficients of T on DV across 4 groups?
I wonder how MV1 moderates the association of MV2 X T with DV
and how MV2 moderates the association of MV1 X T with DV.

And i would like to know hot to express the group difference of coefficient in publish.
In previous articles, they used Wald test or Cohen's d.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

```
library(emmeans)

emt = emtrends(m, ~ MV1  * MV2, var = "T")

emt    # list the estimated slopes at each factor combination
pairs(emt)   # pairwise comparisons of these slopes
```

You can do restricted comparisons via adding, say, `by = "MV2"`. You may also average these slopes over one of the factors, for example,

```
emmeans(emt, ~ MV1)
pairs(.Last.value)
```

Note: To display the fitted lines (whose slopes are summarized in `emt`), use

```
emmip(m, MV1 - T | MV2, cov.reduce = range)
    # or #
emmip(m, MV1 * MV2 ~ T, cov.reduce = range)
```

(Depending on whether you want two panels with two lines each, or one panel with all four lines.) The `emmip()` call shown in the other answer will plot only single points, because predictions for numeric predictors are made by default only at their mean. We specified instead to use the minimum and maximum `T` values.

Answer (score 1):

As a first step, I want to note that you can reconstruct the coefficients for each of the groups of interest as follows. One thing you should do is make sure that T==0 is meaningful in your data, otherwise these coefficients will be less clear:

```
MV1 = 0 and MV2 = 0 - Coefficient of T
MV1 = 1 and MV2 = 0 - Coefficient for MV1 when T==0 and Coefficient of MV1:T when T>=1
MV1 = 0 and MV2 = 1 - Coefficient for MV2 when T==0 and Coefficient of MV2:T when T>=1
MV1 = 1 and MV2 = 1 - Coefficient for MV1:MV2 when T==0 and Coefficient of MV1:MV2:T when T>=1
```

I would suggest using something like `emmeans` for testing specific linear hypotheses regarding these groups beyond what is given in the regression table. The [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/interactions.html) on interactions will be particularly helpful for you:

```
emmip(m, MV1 ~ T | MV2) #graph showing how the moderation of MV1 by T varies across levels of MV2
```

Another handy package is `ggeffects`, which will give you marginal effect estimates for the groups and a graph of the interaction effects. For example (see also [documentation](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/ggeffects.html#two-way-three-way-and-four-way-interactions)):

```
mydf <- ggpredict(m, terms = c("MV1", "MV2", "T"))

plot(mydf)
```

Comment: Looks like `emmeans::emtrends()` would be very useful here. It estimates the slope of a numeric predictor at each level(s) of factor(s). See that interactions vignette